# How to standardize REST errors in a JHipster app?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jhipster

I have built an application using JHipster as the starting template.

JHipster provides an `ExceptionTranslator` class, annotated with `@ControllerAdvice`, that does the exception handling for the errors generated by a client request in the controllers. This class maps exception types to methods, and each method builds and returns an object of type `ErrorDTO` that is then serialized in JSON and sent to the client. I added my own method for a simple use case :

```
@ExceptionHandler(IllegalArgumentException.class)
@ResponseBody
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public ErrorDTO processIllegalArgumentException(IllegalArgumentException exception) {
    return new ErrorDTO(ErrorConstants.ERR_VALIDATION, exception.getMessage());
}
```

It works very well and if an error happens (in this case a value that is too short) I receive this JSON on the client :

```
{
    "message":"error.validation",
    "description":"The request payload that defines the search terms should be at least 3 characters long.",
    "fieldErrors":null
}
```

However, when the error is generated by Spring MVC itself BEFORE entering the controller (e.g. a required parameter that is missing), the structure of the json received by the client is different, e.g:

```
{
    "timestamp":"2015-11-27T15:08:32.897+0000",
    "status":400,
    "error":"Bad Request",
    "exception": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException",
    "message":"Required request body is missing: public java.lang.String ch.unine.directory.web.rest.SearchResource.search(java.lang.String)",
    "path":"/api/search"
}
```

What is the class (or other mechanism) used by Spring Boot/Spring MVC to represent errors ? How can I unify the type of data sent back to the client in case of error, so that I can have a nice unique template for the error page ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution, on this blog post : http://www.jayway.com/2014/10/19/spring-boot-error-responses/ :

In the `@ExceptionHandler` method, just specify the status code and let Spring handle the rest. It will generate the JSON response, with the same fields as when the error happens before entering the controller :

```
@ExceptionHandler
void handleIllegalArgumentException(IllegalArgumentException e, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    response.sendError(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value());
}
```

Sample response body :

```
{
    "timestamp": "2015-11-27T16:08:46.148+0000",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "exception": "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException",
    "message": "The request payload that defines the search terms should be at least 3 characters long.",
    "path": "/api/search"
}
```